# How to add cassandra table column dynamically?

Tags: python, cassandra

I'm trying to add a new columns to cassandra table dynamically. I'm using below version -

```
cqlsh 5.0.1
```

I'm using python to interact with Cassandra. I have one python list which I wish to add as a column names to Cassandra table.

Python List -

```
['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T']
```

Currently, I'm iterating a list and then adding each column one by one to cassandra table like below -

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster(['localhost'])
session = cluster.connect()

session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS data WITH replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3};")
session.execute("use my_data")
session.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data.my_data (pk uuid PRIMARY KEY);")
names = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T']

for val in names:
   try:
      session.execute("alter table data.my_data add "+ val +" ascii;")
   except:
      pass
```

It is working fine but actual problem is, if in my python list more than 1000 entries are available then there should be more than 1000 hits to the cassandra which will be time consuming. Is any different approach available to add a column names to existing table in cassandra?

Comment: In Cassandra Try to use a fixed data model.And design your data model in such way that you can support your select query.

Comment: You should create a column and enter the values dynamically, rather than creating columns dynamically and inserting values.
What does your query looks like? Build your table around that query.

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra internally stores data as rows, each row has a key (Partition key) and dynamic number of columns (clustering key). So, you can use Clustering Key value for your column names, e.g

```
CREATE TABLE my_data (
     pk text,
     column text,
     value text,
     PRIMARY KEY (pk, column)
);
```

Insert new columns and values by a regular INSERT query:

```
INSERT INTO my_data (pk, column, value) VALUES ('pk1', 'A', 'value A'); 
INSERT INTO my_data (pk, column, value) VALUES ('pk1', 'B', 'value B');
INSERT INTO my_data (pk, column, value) VALUES ('pk1', 'C', 'value C');
...
```

Get all columns for pk1:

```
SELECT * FROM my_data WHERE pk='pk1';
```

**Updated**

Assume, you have table `my_data` as described above and
you want to add some columns and data for a specific `pk` value.
In python code perform insert query:

```
pk = 'pk'
columns_data = {'A':'value for A','B':'value  for B','C': 'value for C'} #dynamic column data
for col_name, col_value in columns_data.iteritems():
   try:
      session.execute("INSERT INTO my_data (pk, column, value) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (pk, col_name, col_value))
   except:
      pass
```

Moreover, you can use [asynchronous driver's methods](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html#asynchronous-queries), to achieve more performance of inserting.

Comment: my columns are dynamic. If I create a table like your answer then how I can add such a 1000 columns after some processing?

Comment: You can perform iterating your names list  and perform INSERT query for each partition key in the table. But I do not see the point of adding empty columns without the data. It makes sense to add column names and data together

Comment: How I can add column names and data together to an existing table?

Comment: I added python example in my answer, but I am not a python programmer, but in general it shows the idea

Comment: you are trying to enter a data in a table which has already columns available. my question is how we can add more columns with data or without data dynamically to a existing table?

Comment: In my example, the table has static number of **CQL** columns, but thanks to field with name `column` is a clustering key, each row (partition key) can contain dynamic number of values for this column. Here is a detailed explanation about dynamic columns in CQL https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/does-cql-support-dynamic-columns-wide-rows