# Can we define cols on the fly in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a nested json object in a Spark Dataframe that needs to be stored in Cassandra. I am new to Spark Streaming and Cassandra and want to know the following:

1. Does it have to be flattened out? I need to access individual columns for processing - how can I flatten a nested json?
2. I know earlier versions of Cassandra (*in Definitive Guide*) it was schema-less, is it still that way? Meaning if first row comes with 10 cols it creates those cols dynamically and if the second row has only 2 cols values (meaning other cols didnt appear in the incoming json) then that row will be saved with only 2 cols. Or do I need to handle nulls before storing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2. I know earlier versions of Cassandra (in Definitive Guide) it was schema-less, is it still that way?

Despite CQL requires static schema, internally, CQL partition is a wide row and you can add columns dynamically using clustering keys. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44408279/how-to-add-cassandra-table-column-dynamically/44412038#44412038) and [this explanation](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/does-cql-support-dynamic-columns-wide-rows).

Answer (score 1):

1: you can put the entire JSON document into one column of text data type;you can also try to map more fields from the JSON, convert them to a flat object and construct a map, which also can be indexed. As always in Cassandra - you have to design your model based on needed queries.

2: the table's structure is defined strictly, and you **CANNOT** add an arbitrary column to a row easily.You **MUST ALTER the whole CF/Table** to do that. On the other hand Dynamic columns, are perfectly supported by CQL3 via
clustering columns ( wide rows ). So adding a column horizontally is not possible
but vertically yes .

Columns which are omitted from the JSON value map are treated as a null insert (which results in an existing value being deleted, if one is present).

Comment: Thanks! For point 1. I added more info. I need to flatten a nested json which can have dynamic num of rows (need not be the same no of values in an array within a struct everytime ) I tried "explode" but that explodes only the col I specify whereas in my final dataframe i need all cols (about 500)